# DELETE in stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to do the same thing with DELETE as I do with SELECT. I can't really figure out how the join works with delete?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 1 inner join table2 2 
 on 1.Id= 2.Id inner join table3 3 
 on 3.id=2.Id
WHERE 3.id= @Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DELETE table1 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
on t1.Id= t2.Id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 
on t2.Id= t3.Id
WHERE t3.ID=@ID
```

Comment: It's not working at all, nothing is getting deleted. All tables are connected to table2, and I have delete rule cascade.

Comment: Do you have records in table1,table2 and table3 with the given ID?

Comment: Thanks! My computer was just in a bad mood for a moment, the answer was working great!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
 on t1.Id= t2.Id inner join table3 t3 
 on t3.id=t2.Id
WHERE t3.id= @Id
```